# How to implement passive authentication in smart card reader?

Tags: android, authentication, smartcard, smartcard-reader, contactless-smartcard

I found that on ICAO 9303_11 5.1:
The inspection system performs the following steps:

1. The  inspection  system  SHALL  read  the  Document  Security Object  (SO D )  (which  MUST  contain  the  Document Signer Certificate (C DS ), see also Doc 9303-10) from the contactless IC.
2. The inspection system SHALL build and validate a certification path
   from a Trust Anchor to the Document  Signer Certificate used to sign
   the Document Security Object (SO D ) according to Doc 9303-12.
3. The inspection system SHALL use the verified Document Signer Public
   Key (KPu DS ) to verify the signature of the Document Security
   Object (SO D ).
4. The inspection system MAY read relevant Data Groups from the
   contactless IC.
5. The inspection system SHALL ensure that the contents of the Data
   Group are authentic and unchanged by  hashing  the  contents  and 
   comparing  the  result  with  the  corresponding  hash  value  in 
   the  Document  Security Object (SO D ).

I'm stuck on step 2. What is certificate path and How to build and validate a certification path from a Trust Anchor to the Document  Signer Certificate?
Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Note that [jmrtd](http://www.jmrtd.org/) already runs on Android, so I'm not sure what you're trying to program, but you might want to join them instead. Say "Hi" to Martijn if you do :)

Answer (score 1):

A certificate path or chain is a sequence of public keys, where each one is used to verify the correctness of the following.

The first key in the chain, the *Country Signing CA key* is stored in the passport during production and has already to be available.

Roughly sketched the process is:

- Select root
- Follow the certificate chain up to that of the passport itself, i. e. verify the signature of the certificate and in positive case extract the contained public key for the next step.

Comment: There you go: https://pkddownloadsg.icao.int/download and some certs are also available from jmrtd: http://www.jmrtd.org/certificates.shtml.

Comment: The CSCA (Country Signing CA) is not stored on the passport. It is a trust anchor, which the terminal has to provide. The Document Signer Certificate, which is signed from the CSCA should be part of EF.SOD, which is a file on the chip of the passport. So chain building is reversed here. We read the DS certificate from the chip and have to identify a trust anchor, which did sign the DS certificate in our set of trust anchors